# store data from sqlite into array to draw line graph, Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-sqlite

i'm retrieving data from the table in sqlite. The table store, date and value which i store as datetime. the data i want to retrieve and put it into two different array. one array for date, and one more for the value.. the data is dynamic.. means it can be add some more..

below is my code.

```
 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_GLUCOSE, null);

    //double[] seriesFirstY = {20,-20,67,180,-45,24,99,-34,-8};
    double[] seriesSecondY = {10,80,-40,-20,135,24,199,-34,80};

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYSeries firstSeries = new XYSeries("Ideal Reading");

    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        int date = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.GLUCOSE_DATE));
        int bbData = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.BBDATA));
        firstSeries.add(bbData, date);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);

    c.close();

    /*XYSeries firstSeries = new XYSeries("Ideal Reading");
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        firstSeries.add(i, mStringArray[i]);
    dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);*/

    XYSeries secondSeries = new XYSeries("Your Reading");
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        secondSeries.add(j, seriesSecondY[j]);
    dataset.addSeries(secondSeries);
    return dataset;
}
```

and i got java.lang.nullpointer at

```
android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
```

Comment: what is the issue here

Comment: first, int[] myArray = new int[8];, the 8 is specific to add data.. but i don't want to fix it. then i can't use it for my line graph. for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            firstSeries.add(i, seriesFirstY[i]);
        dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a ArrayList which is dynamic instead of an array.
In case you really need an array in the end you could then convert the ArrayList to an array.